# Как убрать, а затем вернуть пробелы в предложении?

Tags: python

мне нужно было реализовать шифр Цезаря, справился, но один нюанс остался. Если шифровать какое-нибудь предложение, где есть пробелы, то возникает вопрос как убрать, а затем вернуть пробелы в том же месте? Существуют ли какие-нибудь "красивые"/стандартные решения или нужно свой велосипед изобретать?

P.S 
Вот, изобрёл:

```py
def spaces_injector(message):
    message_list = list(message)
    message = message.replace(' ', '')

    space_index = [i for i, ch in enumerate(message_list) if ch == ' ']
    print(space_index)

    for i in space_index:
        message_list.insert(i, ' ')

    new_message = ''.join(message_list)
    return message, new_message


if __name__ == '__main__':
    message = ' 1kjkj 3 5'
    without_spaces_msg, with_spaces_msg = spaces_injector(message)

    print(without_spaces_msg)
    print(with_spaces_msg)
```

Comment: Включи пробел в набор символов, как обычную букву. Делов-то...

Comment: @Akina, изначально так и сделал, но когда шифрую, то всё ж двигается, наверное, будет правильнее заиспользовать этот 'код'. Просто, когда посмотрел на онлайн метод, в коде элементов был вывод без пробелов, а на странице было с пробелами, вот я и задумался...

Comment: *когда шифрую, то всё ж двигается* ??? ну так и пробелы двигаются. Не относись ты к ним как к чему-то особенному. Символ - он и в Африке символ, а что на его месте ничего не рисуется - то дело десятое.

Comment: @Akina, а пробелы ж, вроде, не должны двигаться... ну, да ладно, спасибо, что посоветовали, гениально-простое решение, хех... думаю, так и так сделаю, а препод сам решит, что нужно, а что нет... кстати, глядишь, а мой 'франкенштеин' кому-нибудь понадобится. ещё раз спасибо

Comment: *пробелы ж, вроде, не должны двигаться...* Это кому ж они так задолжали-то?

Comment: @Akina, Цезарю, наверное, не удивлюсь, если так оказалось, что из-за долгов пробелы организовали его убийство, хех

Comment: chr(ord('a') + next_space). Вместо каждого из пробелов смещение до  следующее пробела. Если последний пробел, то next_space = 0, и 'a'.

Comment: @Akina а если описанная Вами буква используется в текстах?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич *Вместо каждого из пробелов смещение до следующее пробела.* И как отличать число-смещение от числа-кода буквы? *а если описанная Вами буква используется в текстах?* Какая такая описанная буква? пробел и есть буква. Для кириллицы это получится 34 буквы. Или больше, если включить в алфавит ещё и знаки препинания.

Comment: @Akina так первый символ - смещение до первого пробела. Далее на месте первого пробела смещение до второго, итд...  Так и отличать. Задача вроде как не читать эти тексты в таком виде, а упаковать пробелы.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич то есть появляется особая процедура обработки местоположения пробелов. Неразумно... Куда как проще, скажем, ROT17.